# Proper Use of Distinct

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling to make Distinct work in the following example. I am after the following structure: NOT, THU

Please see the code below:

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME; 
 SET @StartDate = '20160727';
 DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME; 
 SET @EndDate = '20160727 23:59:59';
 SELECT ISNULL(
 STUFF(
( SELECT ',' + (Coalesce (Distinct( (wh.LocalDepotCode, 'Code not found')) 
 FROM cgtconsignment c
INNER JOIN dbo.whsConsignment wc ON wc.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference] 
INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID =wc.whsHeaderID INNER JOIN movmovement m ON m.MovementID = wh.RunMovID

WHERE m.MovementRef = 'NT-CZ-006824' AND wh.ArrDepDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
FOR XML PATH('')
                        ),
                       1,1,''
                   )
         ,'') AS [Co-loads]
```

That's what I get if I run the query: THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,THU,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT,NOT

I would like to obtain the following: NOT, THU

Any ideas?

Comment: This has now been solved (good old trial and error). Should I then delete the question or leave it here?

Comment: @LukStorms Distinct worked in the end, but for the sake of exercising I will give Group by a try! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Either post the solution as an answer and accept it (You'll have to wait for 48 hours I think) or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me know if it work or try in similar fashion to avoid distinct, or remove xml path to test the result then concatenate.

```
select 
',' + Coalesce (wh.LocalDepotCode, 'Code not found') 
 from dbo.whsHeader wh
where exists(select ConsignmentReference from whsConsignment wc
INNER JOIN cgtconsignment c ON wc.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference] 
 where  wh.WhsHeaderID =wc.whsHeaderID )
 and exists(select 1 from movmovement m where m.MovementID = wh.RunMovID and m.MovementRef = 'NT-CZ-006824')
 AND wh.ArrDepDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
 FOR XML PATH('')
```